# Customer Account banking system error with variable input

Tags: c++, class, structure

Im building a banking system. in my create_account it asks for account address and phone number as well as other questions. When I go to my Show account info (balance inquiry) I notice its not getting the right address as well as phone number. its showing "garbage". Im not sure whats going on If you can point me in the right direction and help out that would be appreciated.

```
 /********************************************************************
 * Vincent Dotts            09/29/2014                     ch11.cpp *
 * This program serves as a customer banking system                  *
 *****************************HISTORY*********************************
 * WHO                   DATE              Discription               *
 *********************************************************************
 * VD                   09/30/2013          Created program          *
 ********************************************************************/
 #include<iostream>
 #include<fstream>
 #include<cctype>
 #include<iomanip>
 using namespace std;

 class account
 {
    int accno;
    double phone;
    char name[30], address[40];
    int deposit;
    char type;

 public:
    void create_account();      //function to get data from user
    void show_account() const;  //function to show data on screen
    void modify();              //function to add new data
    void dep(int);              //function to accept amount and add to balance amount
    void draw(int);             //function to accept amount and subtract from balance amount
    void report() const;        //function to show data in tabular format
    int retacno() const;        //function to return account number
    int retdeposit() const;     //function to return balance amount
    char rettype() const;       //function to return type of account
    //int validate(int*);           //prototype for function for validation
 };

 void account::create_account()
 {
    cout << "\nEnter The account # (5 digits): ";
    cin >> accno;
    while (accno < 10000 || accno > 99999)
    {
        cout << "Invalid Account # Please reenter";
        cin >> accno;
    }
    cout << "\n\nEnter The Name of The account Holder : ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(name, 30);
    cout << "\n\nEnter Address of The account Holder: "<<endl;
    cout << "Example: 18 First St, Oakland, CA 97836" <<endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(address, 40);
    cout << "\nEnter Phone Number: ";
    cin >> phone;
    while (phone<1000000000 || phone>9999999999)
    {
        cout << "Invalid Phone # Please reenter";
        cin >> phone;
    }
    cout << "\nEnter Type of The account (C/S) : ";
    cin >> type;
    type = toupper(type);
    cout << "\nEnter The Initial amount(>=500 for Saving and >=1000 for current ) : ";
    cin >> deposit;
    cout << "\n\n\nAccount Created..";
 }

 void account::show_account() const
 {
    cout << "\nAccount No. : " << accno;
    cout << "\nAccount Holder Name: " << name;
    cout << "\nAccount Holder Address:" << address;
    cout << "\nAccount Holder Phone #:" << phone;
    cout << "\nType of Account : " << type;
    cout << "\nBalance amount : " << deposit;
}


void account::modify()
{
    cout << "\nAccount No. : " << accno;
    cout << "\nModify Account Holder Name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(name, 30);
    cout << "\nModify Account Holder Address: " << endl;
    cout << "Example: 18 First St, Oakland, CA 97836";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(address, 60);
    cout << "\nModify Account Holder Phone Number: ";
    cin >> phone;
    cout << "\nModify Type of Account: ";
    cin >> type;
    type = toupper(type);
    cout << "\nModify Balance amount: ";
    cin >> deposit;
}


void account::dep(int x)
{
    deposit += x;
}

void account::draw(int x)
{
    deposit -= x;
}

void account::report() const
{
    cout << accno <<" " << name << " " << address<<" "<< phone << " " << type << " " << deposit << endl;
}


int account::retacno() const
{
    return accno;
}

int account::retdeposit() const
{
    return deposit;
}

char account::rettype() const
{
    return type;
}
//      function declaration

void write_account();               //function to write record in binary file
void display_sp(int);               //function to display account details given by user
void modify_account(int);           //function to modify record of file
void delete_account(int);          //function to delete record of file
void display_all();                //function to display all account details
void deposit_withdraw(int, int);   // function to desposit/withdraw amount for given account
void intro();                      //introductory screen function

//      THE MAIN FUNCTION OF PROGRAM

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int num;
    intro();
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\n\n\n\tMAIN MENU";
        cout << "\n\n\t01. NEW ACCOUNT";
        cout << "\n\n\t02. DEPOSIT AMOUNT";
        cout << "\n\n\t03. WITHDRAW AMOUNT";
        cout << "\n\n\t04. BALANCE ENQUIRY";
        cout << "\n\n\t05. ALL ACCOUNT HOLDER LIST";
        cout << "\n\n\t06. CLOSE AN ACCOUNT";
        cout << "\n\n\t07. MODIFY AN ACCOUNT";
        cout << "\n\n\t08. EXIT";
        cout << "\n\n\tSelect Your Option (1-8) ";
        cin >> ch;
        system("cls");
        switch (ch)
        {
        case '1':
            write_account();
            break;
        case '2':
            cout << "\n\n\tEnter The account No. : "; cin >> num;
            deposit_withdraw(num, 1);
            break;
        case '3':
            cout << "\n\n\tEnter The account No. : "; cin >> num;
            deposit_withdraw(num, 2);
            break;
        case '4':
            cout << "\n\n\tEnter The account No. : "; cin >> num;
            display_sp(num);
            break;
        case '5':
            display_all();
            break;
        case '6':
            cout << "\n\n\tEnter The account No. : "; cin >> num;
            delete_account(num);
            break;
        case '7':
            cout << "\n\n\tEnter The account No. : "; cin >> num;
            modify_account(num);
            break;
        case '8':
            cout << "\n\n\tThank you Come Again";
            break;
        default:cout << "\a";
        }
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
    } while (ch != '8');
    return 0;
}
//      function to write in file

void write_account()
{
    account ac;
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("account.dat", ios::binary | ios::app);
    ac.create_account();
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account));
    outFile.close();
}
//      function to read specific record from file

void display_sp(int n)
{
    account ac;
    bool flag = false;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("account.dat", ios::binary);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        return;
    }
    cout << "\nBALANCE DETAILS\n";

    while (inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account)))
    {
        if (ac.retacno() == n)
        {
            ac.show_account();
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    if (flag == false)
        cout << "\n\nAccount number does not exist";
}
//      function to modify record of file

void modify_account(int n)
{
    bool found = false;
    account ac;
    fstream File;
    File.open("account.dat", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
    if (!File)
    {
        cout << "File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        return;
    }
    while (!File.eof() && found == false)
    {
        File.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account));
        if (ac.retacno() == n)
        {
            ac.show_account();
            cout << "\n\nEnter The New Details of account" << endl;
            ac.modify();
            int pos = (-1)*static_cast<int>(sizeof(account));
            File.seekp(pos, ios::cur);
            File.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account));
            cout << "\n\n\t Record Updated";
            found = true;
        }
    }
    File.close();
    if (found == false)
        cout << "\n\n Record Not Found ";
}
//      function to delete record of file

void delete_account(int n)
{
    account ac;
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    inFile.open("account.dat", ios::binary);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        return;
    }
    outFile.open("Temp.dat", ios::binary);
    inFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    while (inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account)))
    {
        if (ac.retacno() != n)
        {
            outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account));
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
    remove("account.dat");
    rename("Temp.dat", "account.dat");
    cout << "\n\n\tRecord Deleted ..";
}
//      function to display all accounts deposit list

void display_all()
{
    account ac;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("account.dat", ios::binary);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        return;
    }
    cout << "\n\n\t\tACCOUNT HOLDER LIST\n\n";
    cout << "*********************************************************************\n";
    cout << "A/c#      NAME      Address            Phone #     Type  Balance\n";
    cout << "*********************************************************************\n";
    while (inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account)))
    {
        ac.report();
    }
    inFile.close();
}
//      function to deposit and withdraw amounts

void deposit_withdraw(int n, int option)
{
    int amt;
    bool found = false;
    account ac;
    fstream File;
    File.open("account.dat", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
    if (!File)
    {
        cout << "File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        return;
    }
    while (!File.eof() && found == false)
    {
        File.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account));
        if (ac.retacno() == n)
        {
            ac.show_account();
            if (option == 1)
            {
                cout << "\n\n\tTO DEPOSITE AMOUNT ";
                cout << "\n\nEnter The amount to be deposited";
                cin >> amt;
                ac.dep(amt);
            }
            if (option == 2)
            {
                cout << "\n\n\tTO WITHDRAW AMOUNT ";
                cout << "\n\nEnter The amount to be withdraw";
                cin >> amt;
                int bal = ac.retdeposit() - amt;
                if ((bal<500 && ac.rettype() == 'S') || (bal<1000 && ac.rettype() == 'C'))
                    cout << "Insufficience balance";
                else
                    ac.draw(amt);
            }
            int pos = (-1)*static_cast<int>(sizeof(ac));
            File.seekp(pos, ios::cur);
            File.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account));
            cout << "\n\n\t Record Updated";
            found = true;
        }
    }
    File.close();
    if (found == false)
        cout << "\n\n Record Not Found ";
}
//      INTRODUCTION FUNCTION

void intro()
{
    cout << "\n\n\n\t CUSTOMER";
    cout << "\n\n\t ACCOUNT";
    cout << "\n\n\t  SYSTEM";
    cin.get();
}
```

http://imgur.com/kV8w5KB
a screen shot of my input

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but who in their right mind stores a phone number as a floating point type? Even an integer type is no good - how would you store a number with a leading 0? You need to show us your inputs and outputs before we can help more....

Comment: What happens if my name is more than 29 characters?? Use `std::string`

Comment: I know ive been overwelmed with work so sometimes i dont catch things. But i just uploaded a link of a screenshot of my input.